# How to change the name of constraint or drop it that has dot (.) inside its name?

Tags: oracle

I have created a constraint named version.pk while back ago on some table. Now, I want to  drop it using the following query

```
alter table user.some_table drop constraint version.pk
```

However it's giving me an error saying `ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option`. I think it's because the constraint has dot (.) inside it and oracle does not recognize the query as a valid one. I wanted to change the name of the constraint to version_pk with the following query

```
alter table user.some_table rename constraint version.pk to version_pk
```

But again the same issue this time with different error `ORA-00946: missing TO keyword` . But I think the reason is the same, as it is not a valid query.

One solution that I have found for primary key type of constraints is this

```
alter table user.some_table drop primary key
```

But my constraint is foreign key type. Is there any way to refer constraint name as a literal text, something like `'version.pk'`, so that query remains valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a quoted identifier:

```sql
alter table user.some_table drop constraint "VERSION.PK";
```

*Note: when you use quoted identifiers, you **MUST** use the correct case for all characters in the identifier as `"VERSION.PK"`, `"version.pk"` and `"VeRsIoN.pK"` are three different identifiers.*

*Note: Single quotes are for text literals and double quotes are for quoted identifiers.*